# Replacing string with sequential name?

Tags: python, regex, substitution

What I'm trying to do is easier to show up than explain. Let say I have a string like this :

```
The ^APPLE is a ^FRUIT
```

using regular expression re.sub(), I want to get this :

```
The ^V1 is a ^V2
```

see how they are incremental. But now comes the harder case :

```
The ^X is ^Y but ^X is not ^Z
```

should be translated to this :

```
The ^V1 is ^V2 but ^V1 is not ^V3
```

i.e. if it repeats then it preserves the substitution i.e ^X => ^V1 case.

I hear the substitution can be a function, but cant get it right.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/re-sub-regex-substitution/problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching it turns out there is a solution for multiple replacement using `re` module and `dict.setdefault`, if your terms can contains number use this pattern `'\^\w[\w\d]*'`:

```
import re

string = 'The ^X is ^Y but ^X is not ^Z'
terms = {}
print(re.sub('\^\w+', lambda match: terms.setdefault(match.group(0), '^V{}'.format(len(terms)+1)), string))
```

Output:

```
  The ^V1 is ^V2 but ^V1 is not ^V3
```

`sub` check the `type` of replacement argument if it's a `str` type it replace the match directly with it, if it's a `function` it calls that method with `match` as argument and replace the match with the `returned value`.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you don't need `re`. String operations will do the job:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sequential(str_):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    tokens = str_.split()
    for i in tokens:
        if i.startswith('^') and i not in d:
            d[i] = '^V%s' % str(len(d) + 1)
    return ' '.join(d.get(i, i) for i in tokens)
```

Output:

```
sequential('The ^APPLE is a ^FRUIT')
# 'The ^V1 is a ^V2'

sequential('The ^X is ^Y but ^X is not ^Z')
# 'The ^V1 is ^V2 but ^V1 is not ^V3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple object to handle the incrementation:

```
import re
class inc:
   def __init__(self):
      self.a, self.c = {}, 0
   def __getitem__(self, _v):
      if _v not in self.a:
         self.c += 1
         self.a[_v] = self.c
      return self.a[_v]

n = inc()
r = re.sub('(?<=\^)\w+', lambda x:f'V{n[x.group()]}', 'The ^APPLE is a ^FRUIT')
```

Output:

```
'The ^V1 is a ^V2'
```

---

```
n = inc()
r = re.sub('(?<=\^)\w+', lambda x:f'V{n[x.group()]}', 'The ^X is ^Y but ^X is not ^Z')
```

Output:

```
'The ^V1 is ^V2 but ^V1 is not ^V3'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try iterating the input string word by word, and then doing an `re.sub` global replacement on each occurrence of `^TERM`, using a counter to keep track of how many distinct terms we have seen:

```
inp = "The ^X is ^Y but ^X is not ^Z"
seen = dict()
counter = 0
for term in inp.split():
    if re.match(r'\^([^^]+)', term):
        if term not in seen:
            counter = counter + 1
        seen[term] = 1
        print(term)
        for key, value in seen.iteritems():
            print key, value
        m = re.match(r'\^([^^]+)', term)
        label = "V" + str(counter)
    inp = re.sub(r'\^' + m.group(1), '^' + label, inp)

print(inp)
```

This prints:

```
The ^V1 is ^V2 but ^V1 is not ^V3
```